# Is it safe to ignore hacking attempts based on url to spring boot 2 application on aws?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, security, spring-security

there are dozens of attempts that trying to access "~~~.php", "./env" ..etc files or strange url from other several country in everyday.

In aws configuration, I opened only required ports for service. and the application has spring security config. so those hacking attempts **based on url** only get "access denied"( I check error log on monitoring system sometimes ), there was no problem by now.

but I'm little worried about that if there were "massive"(million?) hacking access to my app server and each access has **different** ip, can **returning "access denied" error for that times**(million) itself cause traffic problem in server? or I can just ignore this error?

I couldn't find the answer in searching.. any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you worry about DDoS, you can setup protections on AWS for that. But it depends on your system architecture.

Comment: you mean like aws waf,shield? thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, but this can be expensive, thus as I wrote, it all depends on your use-case and architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security is implemented as a stack of filter and URL validation occurs very soon in the stack, so the load for each individual request should remain low.

But the second part of your question is about a quite different attack which is a Distributed [Denial Of Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack). If tons of requests coming from high throughput origins reach your server it will no longer be able to answer them all, *including legitimate ones*. Worse, as most Java application are not protected about that, you could crash the JVM for exhausting memory or any other key resources.

Mitigations technics are listed in the linked Wikipedia page, most of them being based on identifying and rejecting the illegitimate traffic. Apart from that, you could try to include in your application or infrastructure a limit on the number of concurrent requests to at least prevent an application crash.